# Why does the code always execute the first if condition?

Tags: python, if-statement, expression

I'm still experimenting with if, elif and else. I don't understand why the first if condition is executed even if you don't choose blue as your favorite color.

I tried changing the indentation but I always get syntax errors.

```
color = input("Whats your favorite color?\n")

if color == 'blue' or 'Blue':
    print("Blue is a great color")
    print(f"{color} is your favorite color")
elif color == 'yellow' or 'Yellow':
    print(f"{color} is your color")
    print("Yellow is awesome!")
else:
    print("Choose something")
```

When I enter random letters, for example, 'sdfd' I should get the result "Choose a real color" but instead I get 
Blue is a great color
sdfd is your favorite color

Comment: It has to be written `if color == 'blue' or color == 'Blue':`

Comment: Python is interpreting your code `if color == 'blue' or 'Blue':` as `if (color == 'blue') or ('Blue'):`, where the string "Blue", being non-empty, is considered True.

Comment: @blorgbeard Thank you very much

Comment: syntax is wrong. ```color == "Bule"  or color == "blue"```

Comment: `if color.lower()  ==  'blue':`

Answer (score 2):

This is because 
`if color == 'blue' or 'Blue':` is like `if (color == 'blue') or ('Blue'):`

And `'Blue'` being a non-empty string it evaluates to `True`.

You could do `if color in ['Blue', 'blue']:` or even better: `if color.lower() == 'blue':`

Comment: Thank you very much. Very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Your test condition have one mistake. Instead of `if color == 'blue' or 'Blue':`, you should do it like this:

```
if color == 'blue' or color == 'Blue':
```

This should work fine! (Dont forget to change the other conditions too!)
The final result should be like:

```
color = input("Whats your favorite color?\n")

if color == 'blue' or color == 'Blue':
    print("Blue is a great color")
    print(f"{color} is your favorite color")
elif color == 'yellow' or color == 'Yellow':
    print(f"{color} is your color")
    print("Yellow is awesome!")
else:
    print("Choose something")
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

For this example it might be easier to use the text method .lower()

```
if color == 'blue' or 'Blue':
```

can be correctly expressed as:

```
if color.lower() == 'blue':
```

This will also capture if someone enters "BLUE" or "bLUE".

This will be easier to read and debug.

Comment: Nitpick: "can be simplified to" is not accurate. "can be *correctly* expressed as" is more like it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - I agree - answer updated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**General Answer**

With any if...else statement in Python with multiple conditions, each condition must be stated explicitly and clearly. So with your `if color == 'blue' or 'Blue'` statement, you are not clearly stating the two conditions. The first section, `if colour == 'blue'` is completely fine, however, after the or comparator, you must state the next condition in its entirety.

The code should look something like this:
`if color == 'blue' or color == 'Blue':`

**Possible Improvements:**

You could also improve this by implementing string manipulation by incorporating .upper(), .title() and various other ones into your code. This will help you reduce the number of conditions in your if...else statements.